# Efficient way of summing all unique ancestor values in incremental DAG

Tags: graph, directed-acyclic-graphs

Let's say we have a DAG that is incrementally build. That means that:

- nodes are being added one by
- when a node is added all of its ancestor nodes must already exist in the graph).

When a  node is added I would like to efficiently calculate the sum of all of its unique ancestor (including current node). 
[image: Sample graph]

For example, when  the node labeled with "7" is added, sum of its unique ancestors is 29. One way (inefficient) way to do is to just walk all the ancestors, and add node's value to the sum if it was not already visited.

The other way is to keep track of ancestors sum at each node. When a new node is added, I can use sums from the parent, but I need to make sure, that some node are not counted twice (node 5 and node 10).

What is the most efficient way to do this?

Comment: Can you elaborate on why the sum of 7's unique ancestors is 7? I would have figured it would be the sum of all its ancestors, as none of the ancestors are duplicated.

Comment: It's 29 not 7 (I have corrected the question)

Answer (score 0):

Well, maybe my calculator is broken, but it shows that 7+18+(19-15)+7=36, not 29, which brings us to the fact that your problem is to calculate a sum of all node's ancestors. There are two ways to compute them:

**CPU-consuming, but memory-saving and easy to read:**

In Python library `networkx` it can be solved with this one-liner:

`sum(DAG.nodes[n]['cost'] for n in nx.ancestors(DAG, your_node) | {your_node})`

Where `cost` is per-node attribute that represents its value.

Here is the full workflow, you can copy it to Jupyter notebook and check interactively:

```
import networkx as nx
from random import randint

# Create DAG
G = nx.gnp_random_graph(10,0.3,directed=True)
DAG = nx.DiGraph([(u,v) for (u,v) in G.edges() if u<v])

# Fill 'cost' attributes
for n in DAG.nodes:
    DAG.nodes[n]['cost'] = randint(1,10)

# Set the start node
node = 8

# Print the ancestors sum
print(sum(DAG.nodes[n]['cost'] for n in nx.ancestors(DAG, node) | {node}))
```

Note that `ancestors` is rather CPU-consuming (**O(n^2)** for every node in non-weighted graph, as I understand) and should not be used for large graphs.

**CPU-saving, but memory-consuming and rather hard to read:**

If ancestors info is needed for all nodes, there is no need to recalculate all possible ancestors for every node, you can re-use predecessors' ancestors. So you should implement this logic manually:

```
def set_node_ancestors(DAG, node):
    ancestors = {node}
    for n in DAG.predecessors(node):
        ancestors = ancestors | DAG.nodes[n]['ancestors']
    DAG.nodes[node]['ancestors'] = ancestors
```

This algorithm checks all predecessors of the given node, takes their `ancestors` parameters, joins them together and writes the result in `ancestors` parameter of the given node. Then for every node you can summarize all node costs in `ancestors` parameter.

You are adding nodes one-by-one, so you can guarantee that every node parent has the `ancestors` parameter filled. But if you want to calculate all ancestors in the given graph, you should topologically sort it and run this function in its order.

The second algorithm is much faster than the first. Here is the comparison of total time of ancestors calculation for every graph node (X axis contains the number of nodes in graph, Y axis - time in milliseconds):

[image]

Comment: Thanks. You are right. The correct sum is 36 not 29 (I forgot to add last +7).Thanks to the answer but It is not what I have been looking for. My graph is incrementally build (node by node) and at each step I need to recalculate sum of all ancestors. `nx.ancestors` does not take advantage of incremental building, so running in again and again when new nodes are added will probably result in quadratic time complexity.

Comment: I understand your problem (i thought that it is calculating pretty rare). How many nodes in your graph have only one predecessor? If there are many of them, you can not to recalculate all ancestors value, but just add the current value to parent's value (if there are few of them, I should think more about your problem).

Comment: Edited my post, I hope it will help you :)

Comment: Thanks I'm not 100% familiar with python library, but my guess is that your solution stores list of all ancestors in list nodes. Since you need to to ensure this list should be unique (so that you do not count a single node twice), you still need to calculate unique set of ancestor  which is memory/time consuming operations for long chains of nodes. 
(P.S: I am not sure if `ancestors = ancestors | DAG.nodes[n]['ancestors']` guarantees uniqueness - it looks like it's jut appending to a list)

Comment: `ancestors = ancestors | DAG.nodes[n]['ancestors']` uses sets, so it guarantees uniquness. `ancestors = {node}` is the definition of these sets. This algorithm is memory-consuming, but time-efficient because sets are built on hash tables so most of their operations are really fast even for very big sets.